# Insufficient privilege error while having select access on table-Ora Error

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I am getting **`ORA-01031: insufficient privileges when selecting a table`**.
Below are the points which puzzled me here:

1. I am having select access to this table through a role which is granted to me
2. This role is granted to me by DBA.
3. I have accessed this table before and I can see whatever the privileges were there, all are same and aren't modified.
4. Trying to revoke the role and again assigning to me but the problem persists.

Please assist on this as possible.

Comment: It might be the case that you are not prepending the schema name correctly.  Unless a synonym has been created you will need to add schema name .  A sample query you are using would help us debug the issue better.

Comment: Schema:A(Mine) Schema:B(Have grant access for a table X from this schema through a role to schema A)                                                    I am trying : SELECT COL1,COL2,CLO3 FROM B.X ;//COL1-Column 1

Comment: As the table definition changed , any column added or modified ???

Comment: Are you maybe doing the select in a stored procedure?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name.. No I am calling as select statement not in any stored procedure.

Comment: @psaraj12 No..Table definition has n't been changed . Any way if any column added or removed or definition changed then does that mean it will nt be accessible to the users who already has access to this table.?

Comment: Can you find this table in all_tables view in your schema ???

Comment: how many roles do you have? the role might not be active or 'default'

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I have several roles and this is active role

Comment: have you checked to make sure the role still contains the object priv?

Comment: I'd ask the DBA who granted you the role to look into it. I'm sure it's something simple we're overlooking.

Comment: Hi All, Any update on this . Please assist me on it

Comment: Does your table have a TYPE column then you have to give separate privileges on the TYPE column

Comment: No type column present.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use your object privilege. If object privilege will be granted by object owner then it will be ok but if object privilege will be granted by any other user who have privilege then it is not accurate permission. Because if object owner will revoke grant from this user who gave to you, resulting all will be revoked.

Example: Object owner is AAA and he is granting select privilege to BBB. Now BBB is granting same privilege to your role CCC (which you have). If object owner AAA will revoke same privilege from BBB then privilege from CCC automatically revoked. It can work only if original privilege granted using "grant option".

Comment: Here in this case we are granting role access to this table from sys schema.Then what's the use of table owner's grant to other schema.

Comment: Never use SYS schema for object granting. Grant using owner of schema.Kindly check granted role is primary role of yours or you need to enable it.

Comment: Check also, role created with password or not otherwise you need to enable it. It should be default role not non-default then and only you can use it directly.